# How can I generate the qrcode client-side that would be compatible with the Ardor Wallet qrcode

Tags: nxt, javascript, ardor, qrcode

I'd like to generate a qrcode the same way the Ardor Wallet generates it, such that it would be compatible.

I found qrcode related javascript shipped with the Ardor node download in ardor/html/www/js/util and ardor/html/www/js/3rdparty, however I wasn't able to find any documentation.

Thanks for any hints or pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The Ardor wallet uses the NRS.generateQRCode() function from nrs.server.js to generate a QR code based on string data into a target div. Both the data and the div reference are provided as parameters. 
This function relies on the qrcode.js library from the 3rdparty folder.